# How to add Flowplayer to a Flex Application?

Tags: apache-flex, flowplayer

I have a Flex application and I would like to add the FlowPlayer to it.  I have downloaded the flowplayer.swc file, but I am not sure what to add to my MXML to include the flowplayer.

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/developer/development-environment.html

Comment: I hope there is an easier solution than compiling the FlowPlayer into my Flex project.

Comment: I like FlowPlayer my self, but why did you decide to use FlowPlayer for your Flex App? Just wondering.

Comment: We have FlowPlayer on our web site and I would like to match the FlowPlayer design and functionality in a Flex application I am creating for the site.

Comment: I see, well good luck with the compilation if thats what you will end up doing.

Comment: hi, I am completely new in FLEX and as per the requirement we need to use flowplayer in our FLEX application. so is it possible to provide the steps that how to use flowplayer in my flex application, which sdk or swc i need to use for that, etc. please reply me as early as possible. Thanks in advance.